# Oracle LAST_VALUE only with order by in analytic clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have schema (Oracle 11g R2):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  num int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (1,'alan',5);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (2,'alan',4);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (3,'julia',10);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (4,'maros',77);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (5,'alan',1);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (6,'maros',14);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (7,'fero',1);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (8,'matej',8);
INSERT INTO users (id, name, num) VALUES (9,'maros',55);
```

And i execute following queries - using `LAST_VALUE` analytic function only with `ORDER BY` analytic clause :

My assumption is that this query executes over one partition - whole table (as partition by clause is missing). It will sort rows by name in given partition (whole table) and it will use default windowing clause `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

```
select us.*, 
last_value(num) over (order by name) as lv 
from users us;
```

But the query executed above will give exactly same results as following one. My assumption concerning second query is that this query firstly partition table rows by name then sort rows in every partition by num and then apply windowing clause `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` over each partition to get `LAST_VALUE`.

```
select us.*, 
last_value(num) over (partition by name order by num RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lv 
from users us;
```

One of my assumption is clearly wrong because two above mentioned queries give the same result. It looks like the first query orders records also by num behind curtains. Could you please suggest what is wrong with my assumptions and why these queries return same results?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. For whatever reason, Oracle chose to make `LAST_VALUE` deterministic when a **logical** (`RANGE`) offset is used in the windowing clause (explicitly or implicitly - by default). Specifically, in such cases, the HIGHEST value of the measured expression is selected from among a set of rows tied by the `order by` sorting.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST_VALUE.html#GUID-A646AF95-C8E9-4A67-87BA-87B11AEE7B79

Towards the bottom of that page in the Oracle documentation, we can read:

> When duplicates are found for the `ORDER BY` expression, the `LAST_VALUE`
>   is the highest value of *expr* [...]

Why does the documentation say that in the **examples** section, and not in the explanation of the function? Because, as is very often the case, the documentation doesn't seem to be written by qualified people.

Comment: `the documentation doesn't seem to be written by qualified people.` ... the documentation for MySQL (which is also owned by Oracle) also has occasional problems.  The bigger issue is that the documentation is huge, and the given size team they have can only handle so much.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - that may be true. But to put something in the Examples section for the first time (without ever mentioning it anywhere else) suggests lack of qualification, over and above the other things you mention, which are probably all true as well.

Comment: @mathguy why isn't LV=8 for all rows when 'partition by' is NOT specified? Shouldn't all rows be taken into account, ordered by name and value taken from the last row, which is in this case the row with name='matej', so the LV would be 8 for all?

Comment: @Marko - are you referring to the OP's first query? What you said should happen if you don't specify partitioning **and** you specify `range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` - did you try it that way? The default windowing clause (which is used in the OP's first query) is `range between unbounded preceding and current row` which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/a-window-into-the-world-of-analytic-functions) in Oracle magazine, here is what happens if you use an `ORDER BY` clause in a window function without specifying anything else:

> An ORDER BY clause, in the absence of any further windowing clause parameters, effectively adds a default windowing clause: RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING, which means, “The current and previous rows in the current partition are the rows that should be used in the computation.” When an ORDER BY clause isn’t accompanied by a PARTITION clause, the entire set of rows used by the analytic function is the default current partition.

So, your first query is actually the same as this:

```
SELECT us.*, LAST_VALUE(num) OVER (ORDER BY name RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS lv
FROM users us;
```

If you run the above query, you will get the current behavior you are seeing, which will return a separate last value for each name.  This differs from the following query:

```
SELECT
    us.*,
    LAST_VALUE(num) OVER (ORDER BY name
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS lv
FROM users us;
```

This just generates the value `8` for the last value of num, which corresponds to the value for `matej`, who is the last name when sorting name ascending.

Comment: All of that may be correct, but it doesn't even overlap in any way with the OP's question, which was: Why does the first query return results that *appear* to use a tie-breaker - it's as if the `order by` clause was `order by name, num`. The question has a very simple answer, but it's not the one you gave.

Comment: @mathguy `and it will use default windowing clause RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` ... my answer in fact does address some of the doubt which the OP has.  The window he cited is _not_ the default, which explains the OP's current observations.

Comment: Err... you are making it worse. `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` **is** the default windowing clause. `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is shorthand for the same, but the Oracle documentation actually uses the longhand: *If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.* For example here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d585679b00333e4cee9cf41a0a54b82f) is a db<>fiddle, in case anyone wants to play with them.

Let me assume that you think that the second query is returning the correct results.

```
select us.*,
       last_value(num) over (partition by name
                             order by num
                             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                            ) as lv
from users us;
```

Let me also point out that this is more succinctly written as:

```
select us.*,
       max(num) over (partition by name
                      order by num
                     ) as lv
from users us;
```

That is irrelevant to your question, but I want to point it out.

Now, why does this give the same results?

```
select us.*,
       last_value(num) over (order by name) as lv
from users us;
```

Well, with no windowing clause, this is equivalent to:

```
select us.*,
       last_value(num) over (order by name
                             range between unbounded preceding and current row
                            ) as lv
from users us;
```

The `range` is very important here.  It does not go to the current row.  It goes to *all* rows with the same value in `name`.

In my understanding of the documentation around `order by`, *any* `num` value from rows with the same name could be chosen.  Why?  Sorting in SQL (and in Oracle) is not stable.  That means that it is not guaranteed to preserve the original ordering of the rows.

In this particular case, it might be coincidence that the last value happens to be the largest value.  Or, for some reason Oracle might be adding `num` to the ordering for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have performed multiple tries and it does not seem like coincidence as correct value is always chosen as last_value. I agree that it seems that ordering by num is executed for some reason, but cannot find any official info to back up this claim. btw.  your second succinctly written query does not return the same row set as first one. You have to leave out 'order by' as this introduces default windowing (and also has no effect when 'max' analytic function is used)

Comment: @EddGarcia . . . I realize that.  I cannot explain that behavior.  The "correct value", though, is *not* the highest value; any value for the same name would be equivalent.  That the highest value is chosen seems to be an artifact of how Oracle works.  I would strongly encourage you to use `MAX()` for this purpose.

Comment: "In my reading of this", you say. Reading, from where? What you say after that is very sensible (a very good assumption), but you didn't read it anywhere. In fact, the Oracle documentation does say just the opposite; Oracle **chose** to make the function *deterministic* when `range` is used in the windowing clause. They made it so by always selecting the LARGEST value from the tied rows.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Yes, I just posted it.